# When would you use the optional argument thisArg for the filter prototype?

Tags: javascript

`var new_array = arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])`

As I understand, the optional argument thisArg just changes the array you are calling filter on.

It seems as though:

```
arr.filter(callback, arr2);
```

is the equivalent of:

```
arr2.filter(callback)
```

Is there any use for thisArg? Why is it an option?

Comment: It is the `this` value inside the callback, not the array

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Parameters)

Comment: What is your callback? I'm curious what you did to come to the conclusion that they were equivalent. Perhaps it will reveal some other teachable moment that will better answer your question.

Comment: I didn't have a specific implementation of a callback, I was trying to understand how thisArg was used, and made the incorrect assumption that it changed the array value of `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `this` value inside the callback, not the array. Perhaps the only useful practical case:

```
arr.filter(obj.fn.bind(obj)) === arr.filter(obj.fn, obj)
```

Comment: What is a use case for this?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's important for `fn` to be inside `obj`. You really should explain a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't change what the array is, it changes the value of `this` within the callback function. The feature is only useful if you're using `this` inside the callback.

In this example, it's used to dynamically change what gets filtered.

```js
function myFilter(e) {
  return e === this.val;
}

var arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2];

console.log(arr.filter(myFilter, {val: 1}));
console.log(arr.filter(myFilter, {val: 2}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function find(arr, searchValue) {
return arr.filter(function(val){
    return val === searchValue;
})[0];}

let newArray = arr.filter(callback(currentValue[, index, [array]]) { return element for newArray, if true }[, thisArg]);
```

[MDS web doc Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
find([1,2,3,4,5], 3) // 3
find([1,2,3,4,5], 10) // undefined
```

I good way to look at this is to look at a question.

Write a function that has an array and a number as second parameter, return the second parameter if found in the array or return undefined if not.